# Dropwdown Menu Goes Offscreen with CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

Working on a website with a dropdown menu (no Bootstrap).

Having a problem where the dropdown extends offscreen. Looked up a few people having similar issues, and they recommended using right/left properties, but I can't seem to get it working.

The idea is to have the two lis within the div come down as a dropdown menu when the user clicks the fa-language element. Any suggestions?

Thanks

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #B0BDC9;
}

#navbar {
  padding: 1.25%;
  background: #2F3236;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right;
  color: #B0BDC9;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #B0BDC9;
  background-color: #2F3236;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-container ul {
  display: block;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-container ul li {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  left: auto;
  right: ;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-container {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #2F3236;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="personal_website.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="navbar">
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_me.html">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
  <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <div class="navbar-right">
    <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-language"></i></a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <ul>
          <li>English</li>
          <li>Spanish</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h2 class="home-text">Text</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: What about adding 'right: 0' to your absolutely positioned 'dropdown-container' div? This will position it to the right of its parent instead of the default.

Comment: Simple and worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pls check in below link](http://jsfiddle.net/de6qf1hn/)

```
enter code here
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #B0BDC9;
}

#navbar {
  padding: 1.25%;
  background: #2F3236;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

#navbar li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right;
  color: #B0BDC9;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-container {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    right: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #B0BDC9;
    background-color: #2F3236;
    min-width: 110px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-container ul {
  display: block;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -10px;
      width: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-container ul li {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  left: auto;
  right: ;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-container {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #2F3236;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="personal_website.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="navbar">
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_me.html">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
  <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <div class="navbar-right">
    <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-language"></i></a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <ul>
          <li>English</li>
          <li>Spanish</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <h2 class="home-text">Text</h2>
</div>
```